# SDF Read Write Restrictions

Tags: sdf

We have a Desktop application which writes to a .sdf file in the Apps User location on the system. Currently there is a restriction on our corporate settings that does not allow to write to this file. Does anyone know of a fix for this, or has experienced this from their network admin before

Answer (score 0):

Check if the folder is "read only"